# Вопрос по ООП. Конкретный пример

Tags: java, ооп

Класс - реализация интерфейса, описывающего работника.
У каждого работника может быть менеджер, у каждого менеджера может быть менеджер итд. Менеджер не объект данного класса.
Функция setManager устанавливает менеджера работнику, getManagerName возварщает его имя.
Вопрос - как обратиться к полям объекта manager и почему я не могу этого сделать? Ибо в отладчике значения переменных посмотреть можно.

```
String name;
public Object manager;

public void setManager(Employee manager) {
    this.manager = manager;
}
public String getManagerName() {
    if (manager != null) {
        return manager.name; // не работает
    }  

 else {
           return null; 
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете обратиться к полям объекта `manager`, потому что этот член класса объявлен как тип `Object`, у которого нет поля `name`. Вы же знаете тип менеджера:

```
private Employee manager;

public void setManager(Employee manager) {
  this.manager = manager;
}

public String getManagerName() {
  if (manager != null) {
    return manager.name; // работает
  } else {
    return null; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Впринципе никак не получится обратится к полю объекта, если оно не прописано в классе?